# Android Proguard - Internet connectivity issue after exporting application

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

I am currently exporting application while proguard is enabled and the issue is that the application works fine but application is deployed without proguard but if exported and deployed while proguard is enabled the application gives error that internet is not connected. following is the proguard file text

```
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-dontwarn com.example.google.tv.**
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn org.ksoap.**
-dontwarn android.view.**
-dontwarn android.graphics.**
-dontwarn android.content.**
-dontwarn android.util.**
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
#-libraryjars libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar
#-libraryjars libs/android-support-v4.jar
```

If I remove

```
-dontwarn android.view.**
-dontwarn android.graphics.**
-dontwarn android.content.**
-dontwarn android.util.**
```

then here is the log that I receive

```
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project] Note: there were 4 duplicate class definitions.
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project] Warning: library class android.content.res.XmlResourceParser extends or implements program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project] Warning: library class android.content.Intent depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project] Warning: library class android.content.IntentFilter depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project] Warning: library class android.content.IntentFilter depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project] Warning: library class android.content.res.ColorStateList depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project] Warning: library class android.view.LayoutInflater depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project] Warning: library class android.view.LayoutInflater depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project] Warning: there were 13 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project]          You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project]          be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project]     at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project]     at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2013-08-02 10:29:04 - Project]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Comment: Have you added any additional library?

Comment: i have added a google tv navigation library .. you can check the package in the properties file '-dontwarn com.example.google.tv.**'

Comment: use `-libraryjars` instead of `-dontwarn`

Comment: Are you talking about '-dontwarn android.view.**
-dontwarn android.graphics.**
-dontwarn android.content.**
-dontwarn android.util.**'

Comment: or left nav bar library?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the package `org.xmlpull.v1` from your libraries. It is already present in the Android runtime (which gets precedence anyway). Adding duplicate packages increases the application size at best, and it can cause versioning problems at worst. In this case, ProGuard detects some dependency conflicts.

Note that is "ProGuard", not "Progaurd".

Comment: Sir, can you elaborate your answer a little bit more. As if 'org.xmlpull.v1' should be removed/excluded from Progaurd or it should be somehow removed from project or ignored in progaurd?